# Prove that $T$ satisfies the hypotheses of the contraction mapping principle.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, contraction-mapping

> Let $T: C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ be defined by $Tf(x) = x + \int_{0}^{x}tf(t)\,dt$. Prove that $T$ satisfies the hypotheses of the contraction mapping principle. Show that the fixed point is a solution to the differential equation $f'(x) = xf(x) + 1$.

How is my proof? I'm pretty iffy on it, though it seems right. I am specifically concerned about when I drop the sup term and then reintroduce it.

\begin{align*}
    d(Tf,Tg) &= \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \Biggl\lvert \biggl( x + \int_{0}^{x}tf(t)\,dt \biggr) - \biggl( x + \int_{0}^{x}tg(t)\,dt \biggr) \Biggr\rvert \\
    &=  \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \Biggl\lvert \int_{0}^{x} t\,\bigl(f(t)-g(t)\bigr)\,dt \Biggr\rvert \\
    &\leq \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int_{0}^{x} t\, \bigl\lvert f(t)-g(t) \bigr\rvert\,dt \\
    &= \int_{0}^{1} t\, \bigl\lvert f(t)-g(t) \bigr\rvert\,dt \\
    &\leq \int_{0}^{1} t\, \biggl(\, \sup_{t\in [0,1]} \lvert f(t)-g(t) \rvert \biggr) \, dt \\
    &= \int_{0}^{1} t\, d(f,g) \,dt \\
    &= d(f,g) \int_{0}^{1} t \,dt \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} d(f,g)
\end{align*}
Now, suppose we have a fixed point $f$. We know that
$$
T(f) = T\Bigl(\, \lim_{n \to \infty} T^n(f) \Bigr) 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} T^{n+1}(f) = f, 
$$
and so
$$
f(x) = T(f(x)) = x + \int_{0}^{x}tf(t)\, dt 
\quad\implies\quad 
f'(x) = 1 + xf(x)
$$
by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the fact that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @MartinR Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

All of the inequalities you have stated are correct.

One method to justify the inequality
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int_{0}^{x}t|f(t)-g(t)|\,{\rm d}t = \int_{0}^{1}t|f(t)-g(t)|\,{\rm d}t$$
is to note that from the definition of the supremum, it is sufficient to show that
$$\int_{0}^{x}t|f(t) - g(t)|\,{\rm d}t \leq \int_{0}^{1}t|f(t)-g(t)|\,{\rm d}t$$
for every $x\in [0,1]$.

Fix $x\in [0,1]$. Consider the function $\phi :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\phi (t) := \begin{cases} t|f(t)-g(t)| & t\in [0,x], \\ 0 & t\in (x,1], \end{cases}$$
and the function $\psi : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\psi (t) := t|f(t)-g(t)|.$$
Both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are integrable, either using the Riemann integral or the definition involving limits of step functions. As $t|f(t)-g(t)| \geq 0$ for every $t\in [0,1]$, it follows that $\phi (t) \leq \psi (t)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. A direct consequence of this is
$$\int_{0}^{1}\phi (t)\,{\rm d}t \leq \int_{0}^{1}\psi (t)\,{\rm d}t.$$
However,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\phi (t)\,{\rm d}t = \int_{0}^{x}t|f(t)-g(t)|\,{\rm d}t$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{1}\psi (t)\,{\rm d}t = \int_{0}^{1}t|f(t)-g(t)|\,{\rm d}t.$$
Therefore,
$$\int_{0}^{x}t|f(t) - g(t)|\,{\rm d}t \leq \int_{0}^{1}t|f(t)-g(t)|\,{\rm d}t$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Is the proof overall correct?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct. However, if you wanted to add some more details, I would suggest adding some explanation as to why that inequality holds, and a bit more explanation as to why $f(x) = x + \int_{0}^{x}tf(t)\,{\rm d}t$ implies $f'(x) = 1 + xf(x)$.